# Find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{3^nn}$ - What is wrong with my solution?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have to find the sum of the following power series:

`NOTE: please assume that x is in the convergence domain`.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{3^nn}$$

## My solution:

1. $$S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{3^nn} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3^nn}x^{n-1}$$
2. $$xS(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^nn}x^n $$
3. $$(xS(x))' = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^nn}nx^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n}x^{n-1}$$
4. $$x \cdot (xS(x))' = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n}x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{3^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \bigg(\frac{x}{3}\bigg)^n = \frac{\frac{x}{3}}{1 - \frac{x}{3}} = \frac{x}{3}(1 - \frac{3}{x}) = \frac{x}{3} - 1.$$
5. $$(xS(x))' = \frac{1}{x}(\frac{x}{3}-1) = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{x}.$$
6. $$xS(x) = \int{\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{x}} = \int\frac{1}{3} - \int\frac{1}{x} = \frac{x}{3} -\ln|x|.$$
7. $$S(x) = \frac{1}{x}(\frac{x}{3}-\ln|x|) = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{\ln|x|}{x}$$

So I got that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{3^nn} = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{\ln|x|}{x}.$

My professor claims that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{3^nn} = -\frac{1}{x} \ln|\frac{x}{3} - 1|.$

Where I made a mistake in my solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In step 4, you claim $$\frac{x/3}{1-\frac{x}{3}} = \frac{x}{3}\left(1-\frac{3}{x}\right),$$ which is wrong. It's $$\frac{x}{3-x}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer : Probably you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: $\dfrac{x/3}{1-(x/3)} = \dfrac x3\left(\dfrac{1}{1-\frac x3}\right)$.  But the simpler way to do it is to multiply the numerator and denominator of $\dfrac{x/3}{1-(x/3)}$ by $3$, getting $x$ in the numerator and $3-x$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is in step 4, where you claim

$$\frac{\frac{x}{3}}{1-\frac{x}{3}} = \frac{x}{3}\left(1 - \frac{3}{x}\right).$$

The correct value is

$$\frac{\frac{x}{3}}{1-\frac{x}{3}} = \frac{x}{3-x},$$

which then leads to

$$\begin{gather}
(x\cdot S(x))' = \frac{1}{3-x}\\
x\cdot S(x) = -\log (3-x) + C\\
S(x) = -\frac{\log (3-x)}{x} + \frac{C}{x}.
\end{gather}$$

Looking at the series, we can determine the integration constant $C$ and obtain

$$S(x) = -\frac{1}{x}\log \left(1-\frac{x}{3}\right).$$

By the series, we have $S(0) = \frac13$, a finite value, so we must choose $C$ so that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{C - \log (3-x)}{x}$$

exists, and that means the numerator must vanish if we insert $x = 0$, so $C - \log (3-0) = 0 \iff C = \log 3$. Now we can write

$$\log 3 - \log (3-x) = \log \frac{3}{3-x} = -\log \frac{3-x}{3} = -\log \left(1-\frac{x}{3}\right).$$

Comment: I think it might help if you explained how $C$ is $-\ln(3)$

Comment: True. Give me a few minutes.